# Common Hadiths between Sunni and Shia

Tags: hadith, sunni, shiism

As far as I know, Sunni and Shia share some common hadiths. Is there any book that compiles all those common hadith?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such source, but often Shi'a attribute known ahadith narrated by Sahabah according to Sunni sources to their Imams.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be difficult to provide accurate statistics on this question, and I do not know the exact source for it, for example:
62 volumes of common hadiths between Shiites and Sunnis were unveiled by Ayatollah Takhiri, Ayatollah Mohsen Araki, Fazel Maliki and Allama Sheikh Hail Abdul Hafiz.

Source:

https://www.tasnimnews.com/fa/news/1393/12/18/680140 and https://www.isna.ir/news/93101709497/